# Is there a name to the git strategy that does not have a develop branch?

Tags: git

For my production project's I've been using three branches, `master`, `develop` and the particular feature I'm developing.

I would create a branch from `develop` and then create the feature and then merge back to `develop` (squash and merge).

When I push to production, I would create a merge commit from `develop` into `master`.

The situation I find myself in is that features would spend a long time on `develop` when they can already be pushed.

I think I've read somewhere about not having a `develop` branch.

I would still have staging API's and staging version of the UI.

What is the name of this strategy and what are your experiences with it?

Comment: How would you determine the version running at the staging API? Essentially, what runs on your staging API is a kind of develop branch. Unless you run individual feature branches at the staging API, which may be a bad idea because then you aren’t testing the interaction of the features before the release.

Comment: don't know if this is the exact name, but when everything is checked directly into master (or in svn trunk), we called it "trunk only development". And it is generally considered bad practice.

Comment: What is the real problem you are having? It seems like it is that you rarely release your code. It is completely separate issue. OTOH, if releases are blocked by develop branch being unstable, perhaps you want to keep it separate, but cherry-pick specific features into release branch (i.e. master).

Comment: In case my comment sounds to harsh, it's not what I intended. It is natural to question the flow in this case. But the real answer is perhaps just "don't change the flow, just release more often". As long as the code is stable, nothing stops your from merging devel to master every day, or even every hour, and pushing it to prod.

Answer (score 1):

I think, what you are talking about which does not contain a `develop` branch is [Git Feature branch workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow). There are many git workflows. Which one is better depends on the project.

One of the most popular workflows is [Gitflow worlflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows). I think currently you are following this workflow.

[Here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows) you can find some comparisons among the workflows and decide which one suits you most.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep feature branches, that's the "github flow".

If you don't want also the feature branches and only commit to master, that's the "trunk base development". With this work flow, which is very good to do continuous deployment, you surely will have to use 'toggle feature' (also name 'feature flags',...)